# Calculate the next position of a point in a window

Tags: math, geometry, ocaml

Height = 600
Width = 100

I have a point (x,y) that moves and it's initialized at a random position in the beginning, I'd like to calculate it's next position with sin and cos. 
the next position maybe at ( if i move with 4 pixels ) x+4 y+4 or x-4 y-4 or x+4 y-4 etc... ( a random direction ).
and if it arrives at the limit of the window it must reappear on the other side of the window.

So if you please could nudge me on the right track I would be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried using a modulus operation?

Comment: Why would I use a modulus operation ?

Comment: Because it would easily take care of the "reappear on the other side of the window".

Comment: it's not a problem the reappear on the other side of the window. my problem is calculating the next position of the point.

Comment: `a random direction`. What kind of direction? up,down,left,right? then you don't need sin and cos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving a very clear description of the desired motion.

Let's say you want the point to move a little bit in a random direction at each timestep, and your problem is translating the idea of a random direction into x and y increments. Let's say the little bit is 4.

One way to do this would be to choose a random angle theta between 0 and 2 * pi. Then your x increment is 4 * cos theta and your y increment is 4 * sin theta.

I have a fear that you were supposed to figure this out for yourself. If this is an assignment, please think about it enough to show some code that SO can critique for you.